# Erro persistente no download de dados financeiros com a biblioteca yfinance

Tags: python, pycharm, ciência-de-dados

gostaria de uma resposta do por que desse erro:

Recentemente mudei para o pycharm, quando fui excutar um codigo que ja funcionava perfeitamente no jupyter, no pycharm ocorre falha no download de dados que deveria ser feita pela biblioteca yfinance, esse erro é retornado:

1 Failed download:

- PETR3.SA: No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted
  Empty DataFrame

segue aqui um trecho do codigo:

**import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt**

**import yfinance as yf**

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Importante [editar sua pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/581128/70) conforme instruções já dadas lá. Para evitar duplicação de orientações e outras interações, o espaço de comentários desta postagem foi desativado, mas o da postagem original continua funcional.